# Can I use Jqgrid in my commercial website

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am developing Online training WEB site. I want to use Jqgrid in this but I cannot afford the price. My question is, can I use Jqgrid open source in my commercial website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Answer (score 3):

> The jqGrid is dual licensed and is released under GPL or MIT licenses. This license policy makes the software available to everyone for free (as in free beer) and you can use it for commercial or open source projects, without any restriction (the freedom above).

--[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=154)

So Yes.

[Note: I found this with one google search in around 10 seconds.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jqgrid%20commercial%20use)